# Index out of range exception while writing data into excel using python

Tags: python, excel, beautifulsoup

While taking data from the URL I got an error, index out of range exception in the data[][].

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import openpyxl
import uuid

row_number=2

for i in range(1,3):
  website_url = "https://www.example.com/job_search?page=1&txtKeyword=IT&keyword=&txtLocation=Thiruvananthapuram%2C&page="+str(i)
  res = requests.get(website_url, verify=False)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
  Links = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'col-md-6 col-sm-12'},)

  data1=[]
  data2=[]
  for div_block in soup.find_all('dl', class_=['description-list'],style=None):
        data1.append([line.strip() for line in div_block.stripped_strings])
  for div_block in soup.find_all('div', class_=['details full-width'],style=None):
        data2.append([line.strip() for line in div_block.stripped_strings])
  url = [tag.find('a')['href'] for tag in Links]
  wb = openpyxl.Workbook()


# Write a header row
  columns = [
      ("job_listing_id"),#1
      ("unique_hash"),#2`enter code here`
      ("status"),#3
      ("primary_skills"),#4
      ("secondary_skills"),#5
      ("title"),#6
      ("description"),#7
      ("job_type"),#8
      ("source"),#9
      ("experience"),#10
      ("location"),#11
      ("company"),#12
      ("posted_date"),#13
      ("expiryDate"),#14
      ("vacancies"),#15
      ("company_website"),#16
      ("posted_by")#17
       ]
  ws = wb.active

  for col_number, value, in enumerate(columns, start=1)   :
      ws.cell(column=col_number, row=1, value=value)

  row_number=row_number

  y=0
  id=uuid.uuid4

  for x in url:
      res = requests.get(f'{x}', verify=False)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
      data = []

      for div_block in soup.find_all('div', class_=['content-block-normal','details full-width'], style=None) :
          data.append([line.strip() for line in div_block.stripped_strings])
    
    # Write a data row
      row = [
        
          row_number-1,  # job_listing_id
          str(uuid.uuid4()), # Unique Hash
          'NEW',#status
          data1[y][5],#primary_skills
          '',#secondary_skills
          data2[y][0],  # Job title
          '\n'.join(data[2][1:]) ,#description`
          'NA',#job_type
          'NA', #source
          data1[y][1],#EXp
          data[1][4],#Location
          data2[y][1],#company
          data[0][3],  # posted on
          '', #expiryDate
          '',#vacancies
          '',#company_website
          'example'#posted_by
      ]
      y+=1

      for col_number, value in enumerate(row, start=1):
          cell = ws.cell(column=col_number, row=row_number, value=value)
      row_number += 1
```

Comment: One of your `div` elements is probably missing values, without knowing the actual URL it would be difficult to suggest a possible workaround

Comment: No Actually I'm taking details from url using list function, while checking the data there is no values in data[0][12]. if I'm taking another url, in the same site there is data available in that cell data[0][12]. its working in a for loop na. how can I fix that? please help me.

Comment: "https://www.postjobfree.com/jobs?q=it&l=Thiruvananthapuram%2c+Kerala%2c+India&radius=0&p=1
Links = soup.find_all("h3",{"class:","itemTitle"})
res = requests.get(f'https://www.postjobfree.com/{x}', verify=False)for div_block in soup.find_all('div', class_='leftColumn', style=None)
 '',#primary_skills
   '',#secondary_skills
data[0][0],  # Job title6             '\n'.join(data[0][16:]) ,#description`
            1,#job_type
            'NA', #source
            '',#EXperience
            data[0][4],#Location
            data[0][2],#company
            data[0][6],

Comment: actually I need to write these details from this https://www.postjobfree.com/jobs? site into excel format using python. q=it&l=Thiruvananthapuram%2c+Kerala%2c+India&radius=0&p=1  ("primary_skills"),#4
      ("secondary_skills"),#5
      ("title"),#6
      ("description"),#7
      ("job_type"),#8
      ("source"),#9
      ("experience"),#10
      ("location"),#11
      ("company"),#12
      ("posted_date"),#13
      ("expiryDate"),#14
      ("vacancies"),#15
      ("company_website"),#16
      ("posted_by")#17

Comment: It's better to use the [edit] button to add extra info to your question

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm the new one using this stackover flow and python.

Comment: Hello sir good evening, i'm stuck with a code. I couldn't get the url while using the same code from this site : https://www.hirist.com/search/software%20Engineer-17-0-0-1-1-AND-1.html?range=3 could you please help me for that. I'm waiting for your reply...

Comment: I am not sure which website the script in the question is trying to access. Are you trying to use one script on different websites to scrape job values?  Or the same website with different queries?  Each different website would need a different script. Can you [edit] your question to make it so it can be tested? (and include some of the details you added to the comments) this would make it easier to understand

Comment: I was trying to use above script on a javascript enabled website. but it was not working as expected. Not sure how to work with XHR requests. Could you help scrape data from https://booking.snav.it/api/v1/rates/1040/2019-02-25/1042/2019-02-25?lang=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the URL you have given in the comment, the data is returned as JSON which can be accessed directly as follows:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://booking.snav.it/api/v1/rates/1040/2019-02-25/1042/2019-02-25?lang=1'
req = requests.get(url, verify=False)
data = req.json()  

print(data['data']['itineraryOutward']['description'])
```

This would display `description` as:

```
NAPOLI BEVERELLO - ISCHIA CASAMICCIOLA
```

---

For your other site, you will need to investigate trying to use their API. The following should get you started:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import openpyxl


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36',
    'Host' : 'jobseeker-api.hirist.com',
    'Referer' : 'https://www.hirist.com/',
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer undefined',
    'Origin' : 'https://www.hirist.com',
}

params = {
    'pageNo' : '0',
    'query' : 'software Engineer',
    'loc' : '17',
    'minexp' : '0',
    'maxexp' : '0',
    'range' : '0',
    'boost' : '0',
    'searchRange' : '4',
    'searchOp' : 'AND',
    'jobType' : '1',
}

with requests.Session() as sess:
    url = "https://jobseeker-api.hirist.com/jobfeed/-1/search"
    req_search = sess.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

data = req_search.json()

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.append(['title', 'min_years', 'max_years'])

for job in data['jobs']:
    row = [
        job['title'],
        job['min'],
        job['max'],
    ]
    
    ws.append(row)

wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

Giving you data starting:

[image: Excel output example]

Hope this helps

Comment: How to scrape data from this site https://www.hirist.com/search/software%20Engineer-17-0-100-2-4-AND-1.html. I tried to scrap data using above code but couldn't find any data? could you please solve my problem?

Comment: Unfortunately most websites need different code to scrape them, a fairly generic approach would be to look at Pandas and the [`read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html?highlight=read_html#pandas.read_html) function. This works on fairly static HTML tables